# Разрешение на предоставленые доступа к файлам

Tags: android, kotlin, android-manifest

Сам редактор пишет что ошибок нет но разрешение не запрашивается что делать?
При этом камеру спокойно открывает.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >
    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="34"
        tools:ignore="GradleOverrides" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="32"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Upload_beta"
        tools:targetApi="31" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Котлин

```
package com.kakao.upload_beta

import android.Manifest
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

   private val storagePermissionLauncher =
       registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()) { isGranted ->
           if (isGranted) {
               // разрешение получено
               Toast.makeText(this, "Готово!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
               // openFileManager()
           } else {
               // разрешение отказано
               Toast.makeText(this, "Доступ к файлам не был разрешон", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

           }
       }

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
       ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
           val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
           v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
           insets
       }

       // проверка
       if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
               this,
               Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
           ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
           ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
               this,
               Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
           ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
       ) {
           // Разрашение уже было получено

           // openFileManager()
       } else {
           // запрос на разрешение управение файлами
           storagePermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)


       }
   }

}
```

Comment: `maxSdkVersion="32"` - а вы на каком запускаете?

Comment: на андроид 13 сдк 33 вроде. В этом ошибка?

Comment: Вообще-то `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` уже на Андроид 10 трогать не рекомендуется и без обходных путей не получить, а на 13 это разрешение уже вырезано совсем. С файлами в Андроиде всё непросто - есть несколько вариантов, которые зависят от контекста задачи. Раскройте вопрос - объясните что вы хотите сделать, для чего вам нужен доступ к ФС

Comment: вообще я делаю что то типо проводника но с более урезанными возможностями

Comment: я не могу получить даже READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: посути моя программа будет принимать файли и переносить их по другому пути для приложения где как раз такое нужно так как иза ограничения что то сделать не возможно почти а программа будет  значительно облегчать процесс

Comment: и мне бы хотя бы к read как то получить доступ не как не могу все пробовал

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#granular-media-permissions